# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension - debase-0.2.2.beta6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rubygems, osx-yosemite, rubymine

I have had this problem for a while now. I am trying to start the debugger in Rubymine and keep getting this error. I have tried clearing my gemset and reinstalling it but to no good.

When I run debug the first time I get a prompt to install `ruby-debug-ide` gem and the end up with this error.

`Error running Local: lims-app: Failed to Install Gems. Following gems were not installed: /Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/rb/gems/debase-0.2.2.beta6.gem: Error installing debase-0.2.2.beta6.gem: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. /Users/am029788/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160229-17823-mgpbf3.rb extconf.rb checking for vm_core.h... no checking for vm_core.h... no checking for vm_core.h... yes creating Makefile make "DESTDIR=" clean make "DESTDIR=" compiling breakpoint.c compiling context.c compiling debase_internals.c In file included from /Users/am029788/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.8.4/lib/debase/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.2.1-p85/method.h:14, from /Users/am029788/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.8.4/lib/debase/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.2.1-p85/vm_core.h:24, from ./hacks.h:1, from debase_internals.c:2: /Users/am029788/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/debase-ruby_core_source-0.8.4/lib/debase/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.2.1-p85/internal.h:246: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘x’ make: *** [debase_internals.o] Error 1 make failed, exit code 2 Gem files will remain installed in /Users/am029788/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/debase-0.2.2.beta6 for inspection. Results logged to /Users/am029788/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/debase-0.2.2.beta6/gem_make.out`

I see the error `Failed to build gem native extension` a lot. What does that mean?

When I try to run the debug after this, it tries connecting and fails.

My configuration:
- Rubymine 8.0.3
- ruby-2.2.1
- OSX 10.10.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fought with this a lot.

Ended up adding the debase gem with version 0.1.1 in the application's gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue today, and the reason is C don't have permission to run. So try to run gcc in terminal, and agree it to run, then bundle again, you should be able to install debase successfully.

Comment: Looks like my gcc does have permission to run. I ran a simple C program on my terminal and it worked. No luck with debase yet